# Android: ask confirmation when user clicks AdMob/AdWhirl banner

Tags: android, admob, ads, confirm

I am new to AdMob. I want to implement ads in my game, but I am afraid that users will sometimes tap them by accident.
What I want to do is to listen for a tap on banner ad and then show a dialog window:
"Do you want to open this ad? Yes/No"

Is it possible? And where is the best place to do this, in AdView.onTouchEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what will happen if the user hits Yes? Then you have to programaticaly click the ad yourself. Such behaviour is "forbidden" and can create false revenue.

Comment: Can I do something like this -  put a transparent layer above AdView and listen to clicks in its onTouchEvent. And if user hits Yes, I can return False from onTouchEvent indicating that event was not handled and AdView should handle it.

Comment: Yes you can do that but you cannot have confirmation. The only thing you can do is to have transparent layer above , if the user clicks then ask him if he wants to click the ad. If yes remove the layer and ask him to click the ad again.

Comment: weakwire: could you please explain why I can't do this? Is it "forbidden" or technically impossible?

Comment: It's technically impossible, because the listener needs to return for any further UI (such as asking the user for permission) to take place. Use weakwire's workaround: one confirmation, and then let the next click go through.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I can simply display a toast "Tap ad again if you really want to open it."